# How to convert a JSON object into an Angular object?

Tags: angularjs

How can i make a long string into a key value pair? My JSON object is:

```
column = {
  "column_Name": "id",
  "table_Name": "calls",
  "full_Column_Name": "calls.id",
  "checked": false
}
```

And I want:

```
$scope.x = {
  column_Name: "id",
  table_Name: "calls",
  full_Column_Name: "calls.id",
  checked: false
}
```

Comment: Appreciated for the edition #Anju

Answer (score 0):

To convert a JSON string to a javascript object you can;

```
$scope.x = JSON.parse(column);
```

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: It helped. Though i changed the approach